# Layout structure - card layout and toolbar with angularjs md

Tags: angularjs, material-design, angular-material

How can I with use of AngularJS Material Design lib achieve page structure such as described in the official [Layout structure guideline](http://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/structure.html#structure-ui-regions) and exemplified in the screenshot below? I want to have centralised card breaking the edges of the page toolbar. Codepen example would be highly appreciated.

Edit: related thread: [Angular Material Design layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29080319/angular-material-design-layout/29083672#29083672)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I figured I'd post this to help others trying to do the same thing with Materialize CSS. You can change the height of the nav-bar, and the size/placement of card.

[image]

[Demo](http://codepen.io/zzzian/pen/yJVKGN?editors=1100)

**HTML**

```
<nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
        <a href="#" class="brand-logo left"><i class="material-icons">list</i></a>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
    </div>
</nav>
<
<<div class="row" id="card-placement"> <!-- id added here -->
    <div class="col s12 m8 offset-m2">
        <div class="card grey lighten-5">
            <div class="card-content grey-text text-darken-1">
                <h5 class="head">Title</h5> <!-- class added here -->
              <div class="divider"></div>
              &nbsp;
                  <p>Stuff goes here</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
/* Moves card up into navbar */
#card-placement{
    margin-top:-60px
}
/* Moves Title position up to be level with nav bottom */
.head {
 margin-top: -2px;
}

nav {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #ee6e73;
    width: 100%;
    height: 112px;
    line-height: 56px;
}

.nav-wrapper {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with a little CSS

```
.card_position{
    margin-top:-70px
}
```

Add this class to the card element.